# iOS Equivalent of SecTransformRef?

Tags: ios, macos, ios5, ios6

Is there an iOS equivalent to SecTransformRef from the Mac SecTransform.h header file? I am getting a Semantic issue where there is an unknown type name 'SecTransformRef'. It appears that the SecTransform.h file does not exist on the iOS side and I am trying to get the same functionality from the Mac side to the iOS version. The main objective at hand is client encryption and communication with Base64 encoding.

Comment: It's not just that the header is missing, it's that the SecTransform functionality does not exist on iOS. If you could describe what you're hoping to accomplish, someone might be able to suggest a cross-platform solution.

Comment: @TomHarrington I am trying to do some client encryption and communication with Base64 encoding. Any ideas?

Comment: Matt Gallagher did a category [NSData+Base64](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html). If you want to see a tweaked version that plays nicely with modern Xcode - I've put it up as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Abizern/5629965)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security transforms are only available in OS X.

If you want to make symetric encryption please take a look on doc page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW14

and also

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the references. Do you happen to know if there is Base64 encoding on iOS?

Comment: Please refer to Abizern comment to your question (NSData+Base64 category)